# CSS Image Resizing

Tags: css, image, resize

I have this CSS code:

```
<style>
     body {
     position:absolute;
     background-image: url(art/c11.jpg);
     width:100%;
     height:100%;
     }
</style>
```

As I read on the net, I expected that this would resize the background image and fit it to the browser window.

But no. I think I am obviously doing something wrong (I don't know enough CSS). Any tips?

UPDATE:

I add the hole example (not working):

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>No Title</title>
<style type="text/css">
     body {
     position:absolute;
     background-image:url(art/c11.jpg);
     background-size:100%;
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     width:100%;
     height:100%;
     }
</style>
</head>
<body >
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Any reason you're positioning your body element? That shouldn't be necessary, but it is usually a good idea to set body's margin and padding to 0. This normalizes some browsers quirky defaults.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're going to make this work cross browser, you're better off putting an image on the page and then wrap all your content in a DIV that's laid on top. E.g.

**CSS**

```
#background {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#content {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

If you plan on supporting IE6, then add this snippet:

```
<!--[if IE 6]>
  <style type="text/css">
    html {
      overflow-y: hidden;
    }

    body {
      overflow-y: auto;
    }

    #background {
      position:absolute;
      z-index:-1;
    }

    #content {
      position:static;
    }
  </style>
<![endif]-->
```

**HTML**

```
<img id="background" src="art/c11.jpg" alt="" />

<div id="content">
  Your content
</div>
```

[Code in action.](http://jsfiddle.net/NH4Xg/)

Answer (score 6):

add the background-repeat property.

finished code should look like this:

```
     body {
     position:absolute;
     background-image: url(art/c11.jpg);
     background-size:100%;
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     width:100%;
     height:100%;
     }
```

Comment: I don't know why, but neither of the examples works for me... Thanks anyway.

Comment: just updated the code with amurra's suggestion. Does it work now?

Comment: `background-size:100%;` saves the day.

Answer (score 2):

I dont think there is a way to stretch or control the size of a background image using CSS. However, you could use the **background-position**, **background-attachment** and **background-repeat** porperties to achieve an alternative result..

or you may use some JavaScript putting Image into a lower z-index layer and set the layer as you backgournd, however that is a little bit Hacking there

Answer (score 2):

By using css3 you can achieve perspective image resize,

```
html { 
background: url(bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
}
```

This works in all browsers and ie9+.
The following filters works in ie7 and ie8 too.

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='.bg.jpg', sizingMethod='scale');
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='bg.jpg', sizingMethod='scale')";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the CSS3 property of `background-size:100%` but the support for this property is not  across the board yet and won't work in older browsers.  To achieve what you want you need a bunch of hacks to get it to work.  There are a number of blogs like this [one](http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/) that will show you what you need to do.  I don't recommend doing this since if you have a big image/slow connection you will see the image load. If the image isn't the best quality then it won't look good all stretched across a screen or in a different resolution.

Comment: I don't know why, but neither of the examples works for me... Thanks anyway.